# Basic Functions in python

Tags: python, function

I am having trouble understanding why this function works in python (it takes a list in as an argument):

```py
def minimax(x):
    minimum = maximum = x[0]
    for i in x[1:]:
        if i < minimum: 
            minimum = i 
        elif i > maximum: 
            maximum = i
    return (minimum,maximum)
```

What does "minimum = maximum = x[0]" in the second line do? How does python "know" what the words "maximum" and "minimum" are referring to?

Comment: python does not **know** what minimum and maximum means it just uses them as a name for a block of memory as **instructed** by you / programmer.

Answer (score 0):

`minimum = maximum = x[0]`

Is the same as

```
minimum = x[0]
maximum = x[0]
```

it knows what they are(numbers) because you created the variables and assigned a value to them

Answer (score 0):

Python, compared to some other object oriented programming languages such as C# or Java, does not require a type to create a variable. The instruction `minimum = maximum = x[0]` will create two variables, minimum and maximum, and give them the value stored in the index 0 of the array/list x. These variables will be stored, so Python will be able to use them during runtime.